# Is there a way to simplify this further?

Tags: boolean-logic

I feel like I could simplify this more but I'm not able to.

```
If A ^ B Then
    C = True
Else
    C = False
End If

If A = True Then
    D = True
Else
    D = False
End If
```

Edit: I oversimplified my problem, it is my mistake. C and D are not boolean values but real values to assign to variables in a function.

Edit2: The function looks more like this:

```
If hasFoo() And hasBar() Then
    C = getValue1()
Else
    C = getValue2()
End If

If hasFoo() Then
    D = getValue3()
Else
    D = getValue4()
End If
```

Comment: `C = A ^ B`, `D = A`?

Comment: `C = A ^ B` and `D = A` ?

Comment: Depending on the coding language you could do it in one line `C = (D = A) ^ B;`

Comment: Not sure of what language agnostic solution you want (or why you want it) but this is pretty straightforward in many languages.

Comment: @Alex I was using `=` as an assignment call not a comparison.  This works in C# (if you use & and not ^)

Comment: @chancea: Didn't catch that, thanks. Neat that it works in C#. I've never seen multiple variables assigned in a single statement like that before.

Comment: OP, could you please be more specific about how `C` and `D` are defined as real values and how they are used?

Comment: C#: `C = (hasFoo() && hasBar()) ? getValue1() : getValue2();` and `D = hasFoo() ? getValue3() : getValue4();`

Answer (score 2):

```
C = (A ^ B)
```

if A is a boolean type in your language:

```
D = A
```

or

```
D = (A = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly do

```
If A ^ B Then
    C = True
Else
    C = False
End If

D = A
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why this was marked down... it's (a) simpler and (b) functionally correct, which met the original requirements!

Comment: I don't think it deserved the down vote necessarily, but I do believe @Crowcoder beat you to a _better_ answer because he also simplifies the first statement.